# Facebook context graph api request using app-scoped user id

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

Two users registered on my app using Facebook Connect on iOS with these permissions : user_likes, user_friends, id (and others). (Using Parse SDK)

Now I want to get their mutual likes and friends on my server. The problem is that I only access their app-scoped id and the graph request doesn't works.

Graph request:

```
v2.4/{user_id}?fields=context.fields(mutual_likes)
```

It tells me

```
  "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
  "type": "GraphMethodException",
  "code": 100,
```

Am I mixing tokens / ids ? I don't really know where to search.

API Page : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user.context/mutual_likes

Comment: What kind of access token are you using?

Comment: I'm using the user access token I saved when he logged in

Comment: What? User access token should be used only by user. If you want to get user data offline - you should use AppToken (appId|appSecret). If user granted access - data should be available

Comment: Besides, user access token is limited, and very quickly expires

Comment: It expires in two months. I read this about the user access token :
_User Access Token - The user token is the most commonly used type of token. This kind of access token is needed any time the app calls an API to read, modify or write a specific person's Facebook data on their behalf. I've explained the detailed process of obtaining this token._

Comment: But I'll try with a app token instead, I didn't know about that. Thanks